# Error while accessing android wear data layer

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

I am trying to access the wearable data layer to communicate with the phone app as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/accessing).

However, after writing the following line:

`DataClient dataClient = Wearable.getDataClient(context);`

The Android lint flags it in Android Studio and shows the following error:

`Cannot access com.google.android.gms.hasApiKey`

Can anyone help me with the meaning of this error and how I can go about resolving it.

P.S.: I have already integrated the Google Play Services API by adding the necessary configuration to my gradle files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered that error too (while using a feature of the Google Play Services API):

```
error: cannot access HasApiKey
```

The solution was to explicitly add the `play-services-base` dependency to the project:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
```